# Calculate approximated distance using RSSI

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, wifi, rssi

I working on a project that aims to measure approximated distance between single Raspberry PI and nearby smartphone.

The final target of the project is to check if there is a smartphone in the same room of the Raspberry.

I thought on two ways for implementation. The first is measure distance using RSSI value, second is to calibrate the setup in the first time from many places in the room and outside the room and get a threshold RSSI value.
I read that smartphones sends wi-fi packets even when the wi-fi is disabled, I thought to use this feature the get the RSSI value from the transmitting smartphone (Using kismet passively) and check if its in the room. I can use Bluetooth RSSI also.

How can I calculate distance using RSSI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an open issue. Basically, Measuring distance according to the RSSI in the ideal state is easy, The main challenge is reducing noise that produced due to multipath and reflecting RF signals and its Interferences. Anyway, you can convert RSSI to distance by below code:

```
double rssiToDistance(int RSSI, int txPower) {
   /* 
    * RSSI in dBm
    * txPower is a transmitter parameter that calculated according to its physic layer and antenna in dBm
    * Return value in meter
    *
    * You should calculate "PL0" in calibration stage:
    * PL0 = txPower - RSSI; // When distance is distance0 (distance0 = 1m or more)
    * 
    * SO, RSSI will be calculated by below formula:
    * RSSI = txPower - PL0 - 10 * n * log(distance/distance0) - G(t)
    * G(t) ~= 0 //This parameter is the main challenge in achiving to more accuracy.
    * n = 2 (Path Loss Exponent, in the free space is 2)
    * distance0 = 1 (m)
    * distance = 10 ^ ((txPower - RSSI - PL0 ) / (10 * n))
    *
    * Read more details:
    *   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-distance_path_loss_model
    */
   return pow(10, ((double) (txPower - RSSI - PL0)) / (10 * 2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A question though: should we use n = 2 or some other value, since we're not in free space at home or some room at least? There are objects in the path, for example. On the Wikipedia link you provide, they have values for various frequencies and environments. Using the Office with soft-partition at 1.9 GHz with 2.6, knowing on 900 MHz it was 2.4, and also that Bluetooth operates at 2.4-2.5 GHz, maybe 2.7, 2.8? Or it's best to keep using the free space option for any reason?

Comment: @DADi590 There are multiple models to calculate distance through the RSSI value, according to the radio propagation models. the most common model is named "log-distance path loss model" which also was used in the above code. In this model, `n` is more complicated than a fixed number in indoor locations. Due to the existence of objects and obstacles in the path, we cannot expect to exist the receiver and transmitter in a line of sight. The signals interferences, fading effects, etc will be made by the environment objects.

Comment: @DADi590 Indeed according to the surrounding objects, the `n` value in each position may be variable. Indoor locations are inhomogeneous environments to propagate radio signals. However, if you don't need high accuracy, you can consider 2 for `n`.  Although, probably final accuracy will be only useful to proximity detection.

Comment: @DADi590 And according to the mentioned table by you, Maybe 2.7, 2.8 values are more suitable. Pay attention to these table values are approximate (Probably an average value).

Comment: Hmm I might mix various values of `n` then! If with 2.75 (average) it says the devices are very close (like 1 meter away or less), before I return the distance out of the function, I change `n` to 2 and calculate the distance again, and I return that one. If they're very close, there can't be many things in their path, I guess. Might be a good idea?

Comment: @DADi590 Sorry for my late reply. Your idea looks good, test it in reality!
Although, I think this idea needs more effort to be completed. Because depending on the environment and its objects, the `n` possible values have a more range (between less than 2, up to 8, or even more!). Also, there is no guarantee of securing about we have no obstacle in our path due to close calculated distances in diverse `n` values. because, this equality might be the result of the reflections, interferences, and complexity of RF signals propagation.

Comment: AFAIK, one of the methods to calculate the `n` value is the `PSO Algorithm` (I saw it in academic papers), Although it needs an offline phase to calculate `n` values. Like `fingerprint method`. At last, I think RSSI might be a useful parameter for proximity detection, But it is not accurate enough to calculate the distance in the indoor environments.

Comment: Take a look at: https://medium.com/personaldata-io/inferring-distance-from-bluetooth-signal-strength-a-deep-dive-fe7badc2bb6d

Comment: No problem at all. I'll see what can be done! I'll also read the website and take a look on the algorithm idea. Thank you again for your time!